# Bootstrap Is Adding Conflicting Styles To JQTree

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jqtree

This first picture is what my jqTree looks like when the page is first loaded:

[image]

When I close then re-expand the "USA" node this is what it re-expands to:

[image]

Upon inspecting it in Google Chrome debugger:

[image]

You can see that for some reason the overflow: hidden was added to the element's style! When I delete/disable this element style the tree works as expected and everything is fine and well.

I also have determined that when I remove the bootstrap css from my header this bug no longer happens.

Does anybody here have any idea why/when/where/how bootstrap is adding this style? I added a DOM breakpoint in chrome to the element (on attribute change), but the style is actually set before the breakpoint even gets hit, so that just leaves me even more confused...

This bug does not happen in firefox.

Help please

Comment: It won't be the `overflow` or any other CSS added directly to the element. Chances are, the `overflow:hidden` is just exposing some style bugs introduced by other styles (margins, padding, etc). You'll probably just need to override those bootstrap styles that cause the problem.

Comment: Are there any other suggestions you can give to help me debug and figure out whats causing it? I can give a link to a live demo if needed

Comment: Yes, in the *Styles* tab, disable the Bootstrap styles for the lists / list items one-by-one until it looks right. Then work out the right values to use and add those as overrides to your stylesheet

Comment: I've tried that already, and I also did it for every single parent element as well. Needless to say it did not fix the problem.

Comment: Post the live link then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sure is a weird one. The problem seems to be due entirely to the jQTree styles though it might be affected by Bootstrap's default `box-sizing`. In any case, add these styles to your stylesheet

```
ul.jqtree-tree ul.jqtree_common {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 16px;
}
```

The problem was, those arrows were being positioned absolutely with a `left: -1.5em` which put them outside the parent's box. With `overflow:hidden`, they weren't visible.

Something in the JQTree JavaScript adds the `overflow` property, probably to facilitate the animation.

Comment: The overflow property is not being added by jqTree, when I remove the bootstrap CSS it fixes the problem (and I've also searched through their source). However, I think you're right that something simple like bootstrap's box-sizing may be triggering it. I have a hunch that the overflow style was actually added by Google Chrome as an attempt by the browser to fix the existing problems with the styles you mentioned. That being said, THANKS A BUNCH FOR YOUR HELP!

Comment: @Ring I think the `overflow` style is set in jQuery's `slideUp` animation function.